# Why I can't pass the data to database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've been breaking my head around this. I supose that should be a simple error that a can't find, and I'm looking for new eyes to help solve.

I want to update the content of a form ("myForm") to a mysql database ("dbcerberus") via PHP, and for some reason, a just can't.

Here is my HTML

```
    <div id="form">
        <select></select>
        <form id="postForm" method="POST" action="userForm.php">
            <p>Nome:</p>
            <input id="_nome">
            <p>CPF:</p>
            <input id="_cpf">
            <p>Telefone:</p>
            <input id="_tel">
            <p>Endereço:</p>
            <input id="_adress">
            <button id="submit">Save</button>
       </form>
       <button id="openVideoButton">LOAD</button>
   </div>
```

And here is mais postForm.php and connect.php

```
connect.php
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$db = mysql_select_db(dbcerberus);

?>






postForm.php
<?php

    include_once('connect.php');

    $name = $_POST['_nome'];
    $cpf = $_POST['_cpf'];
    $tel = $_POST['_tel'];
    $address = $_POST['_adress'];

    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbvisitante VALUES('$cpf', '$name', '$address', '$tel')"))
        echo "Succes"
    else
        echo "Error"

?>
```

Thanks in advance.
P.s.: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Hi lucas just consider looking into PDO instead of mysql_connect

Comment: The action attribute on you form needs to be updated to postForm.php.

Comment: besides answers given, you have missing semi-colons for `echo "Succes"
    else
        echo "Error"` and that alone will throw parse errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change this:**

```
<div id="form">
    <select></select>
    <form id="postForm" method="POST" action="userForm.php">
        <p>Nome:</p>
        <input id="_nome">
        <p>CPF:</p>
        <input id="_cpf">
        <p>Telefone:</p>
        <input id="_tel">
        <p>Endereço:</p>
        <input id="_adress">
        <button id="submit">Save</button>
   </form>
   <button id="openVideoButton">LOAD</button>
</div>
```

**To this:**

```
<div id="form">
    <select></select>
    <form id="postForm" method="POST" action="userForm.php">
        <p>Nome:</p>
        <input name="_nome">
        <p>CPF:</p>
        <input id="_cpf" name="_cpf">
        <p>Telefone:</p>
        <input name="_tel">
        <p>Endereço:</p>
        <input name="_adress">
        <button id="submit">Save</button>
   </form>
   <button id="openVideoButton">LOAD</button>
</div>
```

---

Note: The `id` is not used. It does not hurt, but it is not used in a form post. On the other side, the `name` becomes the variable name and the field contents are that variable's value.

---

Also, correct your mysql_query statement to:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbvisitante (`cpf`,`name`,`address`,`tel`) VALUES('$cpf', '$nome', '$adress', '$tel') ")
```

Note: The variable $names also must be spelled exactly the same as the `name=` attribute on the HTML element.

Note2: I am *assuming* that I have correctly guessed the field names for your MySQL database. Please correct them if necessary.

*Mandatory disclaimer: You should also be using `mysqli_` or `PDO`, not the deprecated `mysql_` commands.*

Comment: See, a knew that was a stupid error. I looked at this code for all the morning and nothig. Thank you very much.

Ah, and yes, a was using `msqli` but, I change to `mysql` to see if that was the problem.

Comment: *"You should also be using mysqli_ or PDO"* - "With" a prepared statement. Just using those on their own won't protect them from a possible SQL injection ;-)

Comment: @LucasLeite Isn't SO great? I learn as much on here giving answers as I do asking questions. Please upvote all answers that were helpful -- Quentin has some good pointers my answer does not include.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` attribute of a form control determines how its value will be labeled when you send it to the server.

Form controls without `name`s aren't successful and won't be sent at all.

You've only give yours `id` attributes which are used for *client* side interaction (such as in combination with the `for` attribute of a `<label>` (which you [should be using](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/))).